# MVVM ListView with Viewmodel of type Observable Collection not updating view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, view, observable

My Problem is that I add 2 Objects of Type Files (for testing reasons) in the Viewmodel which is an observablecollection, but the view won't update with the launch of the application.
Here is the Mainview.cs:

```
public class MainView:ObservableCollection<Files>
{
    public MainView()
    {
        Files x = new Files("picture", "jpg");
        Files x1 = new Files("soundfile", "mp3");
        Add(x);
        Add(x1);
    }}
```

What did I do wrong? And how to avoid this mistake? Is INotifyPropertyChanged really needed if I don't change the properties in the Files class and only want to update the view if a new File object gets created?

I got this class:

```
 public class Files:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _fileName;

    public String FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set { _fileName = value;  OnPropertyChanged("FileName");  }
    }
    private String  _dataType;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public String  DataType
    {
        get { return _dataType; }
        set { _dataType = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataType"); }
    }
    public Files(string filename, string dataType)
    {
        this._fileName = filename;
        this._dataType = dataType;
    }
}
```

And this ViewModel:

```
  public class MainView:ObservableCollection<Files>
{
    public MainView()
    {
        Files x = new Files("picture", "jpg");
        Files x1 = new Files("soundfile", "mp3");
        Add(x);
        Add(x1);
    }
}
```

And did this in xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ClientTestDesign.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClientTestDesign"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ClientTestDesign.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
  >
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainView x:Key="View"></vm:MainView>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource ForwardBackButton}" Content="Back"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource StopButton}" Content="Pause"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ForwardBackButton}" Content="Forward"></Button>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding /FileName, Source={StaticResource View}}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding /FileName, Source={StaticResource View}}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is more of an understanding issue. Your `Files` class should be your ViewModel. `Files` should be a property in your ViewModel.

Comment: @KosalaW You mean files should be the observable collection? and my fviewmodel should contain the attributes of files?

Comment: @KosalaW That can not be the only mistake, can it? I changed it didn't work

Comment: I will write an answer shortly. You will be able to understand it better that way.

Comment: @KosalaW Ok ty I'm looking forward to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like this;

Your "File" Class; There is no much change here. But have a look at the way I have implemented the properties and OnPropertyChanged.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
 public class File:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private string _fileName;
    private string _dataType;

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return _fileName; }
        set
        {
            _fileName = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }

    public string DataType
    {
        get { return _dataType; }
        set
        {
            _dataType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataType");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
 }
}
```

This is your ViewModel. As you can see, this view model is quite different from yours. There are some commented properties/ methods in here. If you are planning to implement some commands, that code may be useful.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel1:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<File> _files;
        private File _selectedFile;
        //private ICommand _getFiles;

        public ObservableCollection<File> Files
        {
            get { return _files; }
            set
            {
                _files = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Files");
            }
        }

        public File SelectedFile
        {
            get { return _selectedFile; }
            set
            {
                _selectedFile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFile");
            }
        }

        //public ICommand GetFiles
        //{
        //    get { return _getFiles; }
        //    set
        //    {
        //        _getFiles = value;
        //    }
        //}

        //public void ChangeFileName(object obj)
        //{
        //    Files[0].FileName = "File_" + new Random().Next().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //}

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel1()
        {
           Files =  new ObservableCollection<File>();
           Files.Add(new File() { FileName = "picture", DataType = "jpg"});
           Files.Add(new File() { FileName = "soundfile", DataType = "mp3" });
           //GetFiles = new RelayCommand(ChangeFileName, param => true);
        }
    }
}
```

Your View; Have a look at the bindings. That was one of your issues.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel1 x:Key="View"></vm:MainWindowViewModel1>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource View}, Path=Files, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding  Source={StaticResource View}, Path= SelectedFile, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="28,27,31,146">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= FileName, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= DataType, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <!--<Button Content="Refresh" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource View},Path = GetFiles}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="347,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"/>-->
</Grid>
```

Comment: It worked, I used your code and deleted all my additional grids and column+rowdefinitions then it worked. Thank you, it is better to hava a observable collection as an object in the listview, im glad its working :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ListView's ItemsSource. In this case it's the same as your DataContext so just do this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ... etc...
```

Comment: Did not work, isn't the ItemsSource inherita from the DataContext if it is not set explicit

Comment: No, it's completely separate to the DataContext. It worked fine for me using the code you posted so you must be doing something else that you haven't shown us.

Comment: So there are 2 listobjects visible for you? I did not change anything it doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes, there are two objects in the list. I'd say there's probably something wrong with how you're setting your DeviceContext...I used the ServiceLocator that MVVM sets up automatically and in the MainWindow did `DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainView}"`. How are you setting it yourself?

Comment: @MarkFeldman He uses a static resource and specify `Source` in his bindings. Which is ok. But for more complex views, it's much better to use DataContext in my opinion.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Would have worked as well I guess :( I was 2 blind 2 see that an additional problem had something to do with my additional grids.